# When proofreading a chapter, should I try to prevent a few lines spilling onto a new page?

Tags: editing, proofreading

I am proofreading a novel chapter for the first time. I do not have the other chapters to review. The book is a 2nd edition, and several chunks of text have been inserted, so the end of the chapter is now on an extra page (eight lines only on this last page). As the novel is at the proof page, I am assuming I should try to save lines, so the chapter occupies the equivalent number of pages as before the extra text was inserted? It would mean trying to save eight lines, though. Or is this not important? I am just worried about the impact on the rest of the book. My mentor is telling me to 'follow my gut instinct', but I am struggling...

Comment: This sounds like a question for the publisher.

Comment: Is your concern that indices and already published references would subsequently wind up with different page numbers? (However if this is a fiction novel, it seems a strange question.)

Answer (score 1):

You say you are proof-reading, so you are the copy editor? You should concern yourself with the readability of the text, but not the pagination.

In any case, if a novel chapter goes 8 lines into the last page, that is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As Simon White says, it's a non-issue.

If there were only one or two lines on the last page... then it would be a minor issue. You might flag it, but you don't need to change it. The layout person can make a few simple tweaks to pull the extra lines back, or push more lines forward.